# jquery get value from dynamically created inputs with name

Tags: jquery, input, dynamically-generated

I'm having a form that is created dynamically depending on the value selected, it makes various text inputs and depending if its a new reg the values are empty if not the values are populated with data from a mysql database, when i want to submit the form and make a new insert i try to get all the values from the inputs but no values are returned

```
$('input#send.clientenom').live('click', function (){
    var id_cliente = $('select#clienteslist.list').val();
    var contacto = $('.clientenom input[name="contacto"]').val();
    var cliente = $('.clientenom input[name="cliente"]').val();
    var direccion = $('.clientenom input[name="direccion"]').val();
    var colonia = $('.clientenom input[name="colonia"]').val();
    var estado = $('.clientenom input[name="estado"]').val();
    var cp = $('.clientenom input[name="cp"]').val();
    var telefono = $('.clientenom input[name="telefono"]').val();
    var email = $('.clientenom input[name="email"]').val();
    var acumulado = $('.clientenom input[name="acumulado"]').val();
    var tipocliente = $('.clientenom input[name="tipocliente"]').val();
    var prospecto = $('.clientenom input[name="prospecto"]').val();
    var nivel = $('.clientenom input[name="nivel"]').val();
    var proynom = $('.regname input[name="regproyname"]').val();
    alert(id_cliente, contacto, cliente, direccion, colonia, estado, cp, telefono, email, acumulado, tipocliente, prospecto, nivel, proynom);
            data = JSON.parse(data);     

    if(id_cliente == 0){

    var jqxhr = $.post("php/registrop.php",{"id_tipo":tipocliente, "id_prospecto":prospecto, "id_nivel":nivel, "contacto":contacto,"cliente":cliente, "direccion":direccion, "colonia":colonia, "estado":estado, "cp":cp, "telefono":telefono, "email":email, "acumulado":acumulado, "proyecto":proynom},function(data){
    if (typeof (data) == 'object' && JSON.parse ){

var html = '';
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {      
    var d = data[i];
    if(!d.error){
    if(d.Success == true){
html += d.Message;}
}else{
            alert(d.error);
    }}
    alert(d.Message);
    }else{

    alert("error no se puede parsear");
    }




        } )}else{
            var jqxhr = $.post("php/registrop.php",{"id_cliente":id_cliente, "proyecto":proynom},function(data){
                        data = JSON.parse(data);     
    if (typeof (data) == 'object' && JSON.parse ){

var html = '';
var len = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {      
    var d = data[i];
    if(!d.error){
if(d.Success == true){
html += d.Message;
}

}else{
    alert(html);
    }}
            alert(d.error);
    alert("error no se puede parsear");
    }


        } )
            }
    });
```

the alert is just to debug to see the values but the only value i get is id_cliente val no other value is added do i need to bind o delegate the inputs? also my submit button is type button not submit so it wont reload the page thanks in advance!

the form is created this way:

```
  function selectedcliente(){
var id_clientea = $('select#clienteslist.list').val();
if($('form#info.customForm').length > 0 || id_clientea == ""){

    $('.clienteinfo').empty();
            }
if(id_clientea == 0){
var html = '';
html += '<form class="customForm" id="info">' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="contacto">Contacto</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="contacto" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="contactoinfo">Nombre del contacto del cliente</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="cliente">Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="cliente" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="clienteinfo">Nombre de la empresa/cliente</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="direccion">Direccion</label>' + 
'<input type="text" name="direccion" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="direccioninfo">Direccion de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="colonia">Colonia</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="colonia" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="coloniainfo">Colonia de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="estado">Estado</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="estado" class="estado" value=""/><span id="estadoinfo">Estado donde se encuentra la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="cp">Codigo Postal</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="cp" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="cp">Codigo Postal del lugar de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="telefono">Telefono</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="telefono" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="telefonoinfo">Telefono de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="email">E&ndash;mail</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="email" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="emailinfo">E&ndash;mail de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="acumulado">Acumulado</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="acumulado" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="acumuladoinfo">Total de todas las compras que se han hecho</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="tipocliente">Tipo del Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="tipocliente" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="tipoclienteinfo">Que tipo de cliente es (Gobierno, Particular, Industrial, Distribuidor, Particular GR)</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="prospecto">Prospecto o Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="prospecto" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="prospectoinfo">Prospecto o Cliente?</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="nivel">Nivel del Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="nivel" class="clientenom" value=""/><span id="nivelinfo">Nivel del cliente (depende del total acumulado)</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<input type="button" class="clientenom" id="send" value="Registrar Proyecto" />' +
'</div>' +
'</form>'
;
        $('.clienteinfo').append(html);
}
else
{
var jqxhr = $.post('php/selectcliente.php',{"id_cliente":id_clientea}, function(data){
 data = JSON.parse(data);

 if(typeof(data) == 'object' && JSON.parse){
var html = '';
var len = data.length;
//alert(len);
for(var i = 0; i<len; i++){
var d = data[i];
    if(!d.error){

html += '<form class="customForm" id="info">' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="contacto">Contacto</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="contacto" class="clientenom" value="' + d.contacto + '"/><span id="contactoinfo">Nombre del contacto del cliente</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="cliente">Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="cliente" class="clientenom" value="' + d.cliente + '"/><span id="clienteinfo">Nombre de la empresa/cliente</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="direccion">Direccion</label>' + 
'<input type="text" name="direccion" class="clientenom" value="' + d.direccion + '"/><span id="direccioninfo">Direccion de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="colonia">Colonia</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="colonia" class="clientenom" value="' + d.colonia + '"/><span id="coloniainfo">Colonia de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="estado">Estado</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="estado" class="estado" value="' + d.estado + '"/><span id="estadoinfo">Estado donde se encuentra la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="cp">Codigo Postal</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="cp" class="clientenom" value="' + d.cp + '"/><span id="cp">Codigo Postal del lugar de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="telefono">Telefono</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="telefono" class="clientenom" value="' + d.telefono + '"/><span id="telefonoinfo">Telefono de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="email">E&ndash;mail</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="email" class="clientenom" value="' + d.correo + '"/><span id="emailinfo">E&ndash;mail de la empresa</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="acumulado">Acumulado</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="acumulado" class="clientenom" value="' + d.acumulado + '"/><span id="acumuladoinfo">Total de todas las compras que se han hecho</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="tipocliente">Tipo del Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="tipocliente" class="clientenom" value="' + d.tipo_cliente + '"/><span id="tipoclienteinfo">Que tipo de cliente es (Gobierno, Particular, Industrial, Distribuidor, Particular GR)</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="prospecto">Prospecto o Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="prospecto" clss="clientenom" value="' + d.prospecto + '"/><span id="prospectoinfo">Prospecto o Cliente?</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<label for="nivel">Nivel del Cliente</label>' +
'<input type="text" name="nivel" class="clientenom" value="' + d.nivel + '"/><span id="nivelinfo">Nivel del cliente (depende del total acumulado)</span>' +
'</div>' +
'<div>' +
'<input type="button" class="clientenom" id="send" value="Registrar Proyecto" />' +
'</div>' +
'</form>'
;
    }else{
        alert(d.error); 
        }

    }
    $('.clienteinfo').append(html);
}else{
    alert("Is not object");

    }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the HTML for your form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.clientenom input[name="nivel"]` is trying to find an `input` with a `name` of `nivel` that is **within** an element with the class of `clientenom`.

This is not the case in your html.  The input is not within `.clientenom` it has that class itself.

Unless you have multiple inputs with the same name, just drop the class all together:

```
var contacto = $('input[name="contacto"]').val();
```

If you do need the class, it should be:

```
input.clientenom[name="nivel"]
```

or

```
input[name="nivel"].clientenom
```

EDIT:  On a similar note, in most cases, there is no reason to do something like `select#clienteslist.list`.  If the element has an ID just use the ID, unless there is some reason you only want to get it when it is a select and has the class list.